# smoothness of solution for second order elliptic problem

Tags: elliptic-pde, smoothness, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Hello all,

could someone point me to a reference that ties the smoothness of the solution $u$ to the classical elliptic problem

$\nabla \cdot ( q \nabla u ) = f \;,\; x \in \Omega$

$u = g  \;,\; x \in \Gamma = \partial \Omega$

to the smoothness of $f$, $q$ and $g$?

$\Omega$ is a convex polygonal domain in $\Re^d$ with $d \in \{2,3\}$. The boundary $\Gamma$ is piecewise linear (can have corners, e.g., if $\Omega$ is the unit square).

I am particularly interested in the (minimal) smoothness requirements for the forcing and boundary data $f$ and $g$, such that $u \in {\cal H}^2(\Omega)$ (not just locally).

I went through Evans' book on PDEs but he assumes homogeneous boundaries and proves only local smoothness $u \in {\cal H}_{\rm loc}^s(\Omega)$ based on assumptions on the forcing $f$. My $g$ is generally nonzero.

Also, would the smoothness theory for the BVP above extend to a Helmholtz problem with a pure Neumann BC?

Thanks for any good pointers!

Kind regards, 
  -- Mihai

Comment: Is $\Gamma$ the boundary of $\Omega$? If so, what kind of regularity are you assuming for $\Gamma$?

Comment: have you looked at Gilbarg and Trudinger?

Comment: @Yakov Shlapentokh-Rothman: I updated the problem definition.

@Willie Wong: thanks for the pointer, I will check it out today.

Comment: For an example of things that can go wrong since $\Gamma$ is not smooth, see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/38054/a-simple-example-where-elliptic-boundary-regularity-fails-due-to-a-kink-in-the-do/38803#38803

Comment: Gilbarg and Trudinger assume smooth boundaries as far as I see. I am going through Grisvard right now to see what I can figure out from there.

Comment: A necessary condition is convexity of the domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grisvard's book is a standard reference for elliptic problems in domains with corners.

Answer (score 0):

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_regularity and references therein.